# html category / sub-category best view

Tags: html, css, treeview, categories

I have a mysql database populated with categories/subcategories, and I'm on the way to build a php/html/css presentation module to show the hierarchy above mentioned.

My objective is to have a simple and clean way to list those categories, widthout getting to confuse to the client (note that there's no "level" limit to the subcategories, so there may be 1 or 100).

I'd like you guys to advise me some visual examples on how to display my categories.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could emulate Mac OS's Finder:

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [novamedia.de](http://www.novamedia.de/press_resources/media/fonelink/fonelink_finder_en.jpg))</sub>

Comment: how do I accomplish that in html/css?

Comment: Off the top of my head; I'd say float a few lists together. Depending on what lits-item is click, hide/show lists pertaining to that selection.

Answer (score 0):

How about a windows-like tree view? People are used to that.

Comment: That becomes too big when the number of subcategories are huge. I need something that allows navigation but don't make the user browsers to expand.